# Placing other Kendo widgets inside Content of Window for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-ui-mvc, kendo-window

Is it possible to use razor syntax to add kendo widgets inside of the Content of a Kendo Window?

Here is an example of what I am trying to do but the kendo widgets aren't loading properly:

```
    <div id="window1"></div>

    @(Html.Kendo().Window()
          .Name("productWindow")
          .Title("Additional Settings")
          .Width(400)
          .Modal(true)
          .AppendTo("#window1")
          .Visible(false)
          .Actions(actions => actions.Minimize().Maximize().Close())
.Content(@<text>
    <label asp-for="ProductId"></label>
    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                      .Name("ProductId")
                      .DataTextField("Text")
                      .DataValueField("Value")
                      .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>() {
                          new SelectListItem() {
                              Text = "Prod 1",
                              Value = "1"
                          },
                          new SelectListItem() {
                              Text = "Prod 2",
                              Value = "2"
                          },
                          new SelectListItem() {
                              Text = "Prod 3",
                              Value = "3"
                          },
                          new SelectListItem() {
                              Text = "Prod 4",
                              Value = "4"
                          }
                      })
                      .Value("2")
                      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%" })
                      .Deferred()
    )
    <span asp-validation-for="ProductId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </text>)
          .Deferred()
    )
```

Comment: I deleted my answer as you say the drop down is fine and the double escape does not work as I expected. However, I would only suggest that if you are going to load something in a window then it would be easier to break out the content into a Partial when using Razor. If you inline the window content then it will turn very unwieldy very fast.

Comment: Ok so lets say I break it out into a Partial that has a ViewModel. How can I make that partial part of the content of the window. My overall goal is to have a single form on the parent page with fields on it, then some of the forms fields in a kendo window. On post of the form all fields should be bound to the view model and sent to the Create action in my controller. I believe I am close it is just about getting these Kendo controls to load in the content of the window.

Comment: I added a answer to your comment below.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the window make another call to ask for it's content. That call will return the partial with the view for the window.

**In Parent View**

```
@model ProductFormViewModel 

@(Html.Kendo().Window().LoadContentFrom("Action", "Controller",new object{"detailID",model.DetailID);
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Action(int detailID)
{
    var detailModel=LoadDetail(DetailID);
    return PartialView("MyWindowPartual",detailModel);
}
```

**Window Detail PartialView**

```
@model AdvancedProductSettingsViewModel

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()...
```

And have the controller return a View() or PartialView().

Comment: Perfect let me give this a try and I will mark as correct. Do you know how I will be able to merge the ViewModel of the partial with the ViewModel of my parent page? Lets say I have a ViewModel called ProductFormViewModel on the parent page and then in the partial I have a ViewModel called AdvancedProductSettingsViewModel. The VM on the parent page includes properties for both the fields on the parent page and the partial. I will need to somehow populate these fields with the partial fields.

Comment: Just to make my previous post more clear: Normally when you load a partial view you pass it a view model right? In this scenario how will I ensure I can pass it the view model from my parent form.

Comment: You would have to load the AdvancedProductSettingsViewModel for the detail view a second time in your controller. Normally, I would break the parent out to be a summary view with a link to the detail record or records. I have updated answer with one solution.